# Delayed ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, future, executorservice

Is there an `ExecutorService` that will allow me to submit tasks without beginning execution until I request it? I'm looking for something like `ScheduledExecutorService`, except that I want to trigger the execution manually without depending on a fixed time delay.

The reason I'm looking for this is because I want to create a set of tasks which may recursively use results of `Future`s generated from parallel tasks in the same set. So I would need to first submit all the tasks in order to get a set of `Future`s, and only then could I allow the tasks to begin executing.

Comment: +1 I would reconsider whether you can simplify your execution model.  Often what seems like a good idea, is actually to complicated to implement efficiently enough to make it worth it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a difficult thing to implement. You can write a wrapper for executor that will return some kind of modified `Future` with `execute()` method and will keep track of all submited tasks, storing them in some inner collection.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am considering other approaches, but if this functionality does exist, this would likely be the easiest way to accomplish my task. I may even consider implementing such an executor myself.

Comment: You might not need a new executor, All you need is a new queue like a DelayedQueue where new tasks don't appear until you trigger them (instead of when their time is reached)

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Yes, I considered that, but it might not be worth the effort, since I need this for a very specific use-case.

Comment: If you are thinking about recursive parallel tasks, consider fork-join: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov I'll have to look into it. But at first glance, it seems you're discussing a different type of recursion than what I require.

Comment: How about trying java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier?

Comment: @HaoLiu I don't think that would help me here. `CyclicBarrier` allows multiple threads to wait at a common barrier after they've completed their respective tasks, but what I need is for specific threads to wait for other threads to complete before they can start.

Comment: @shmosel If I understand this correctly, you may use main thread to schedule the execution. Use barrier1 to wait for the first group of threads to finish and then trigger the second group of threads using barrier2. Main thread only does waiting and triggering, etc. If things get more complicated, a more generalized pattern might be needed I suppose.

Comment: @HaoLiu Yes, I could have run the threads in several stages, but that way I'd have to map out all the dependencies in advance. Ideally, I want to prepopulate a map of tasks, which could in turn use the same map to wait on other tasks. This keeps everything much simpler because each task can manage his logic independently. (Obviously I'd have to ensure in advance that there's no possibility of a deadlock.)

Comment: maybe it helps to understand why you need all those Futures before starting to run tasks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a job for [CompletableFuture](http://download.java.net/lambda/b88/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

- fire execution of first portion of tasks as separe `CompletableFutures`
- then using [`CompletableFuture.allOf(...furures)`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b88/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)) to create a barrier future that completes only when all are done
- then using one of combinators like `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` to schedule next portion of tasks to perform on completion of barrier future

---

But more idiomatic way to use it would be to chain each next task based on future result of some previous one

```
CompletableFuture<FirstResult> firstTask = //....
CompletableFuture<SecondResult> secondTask = firstTask.thenApply(someTransformation);
CompletableFuture<Void> anotherTaks = firstTask.thenAccept(someConsumer);
CompletableFuture<ThirdResult> combined =  firstTask.thenAcceptBoth(secondTask, someFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an alternate approach would be to simply use a [FutureCallback](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureCallback.html) or an [AsyncFunction](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AsyncFunction.html)?

FutureCallback example:

```
final List<ListenableFuture<T>> futures = new ArrayList<ListenableFuture<T>>();
final Callable<T> callable = new Callable<T>() {
    // Some task you want to complete
};
// Submit all your tasks for execution
futures.add(listeningExecutorService.submit(callable));
// ... add as many tasks as you have
futures.add(listeningExecutorService.submit(callable));

// Get a single Future to wait on
final ListenableFuture<List<T>> future = Futures.allAsList(futures);

Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<List<T>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final List<T> result) {
        // Begin other tasks using `result` (the set of results from the first tasks)
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Throwable t) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

This would be helpful if you don't care about waiting around for the second set of tasks to complete, as [Futures.addCallback](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback)) doesn't return anything.

AsyncFunction example:

```
final ListenableFuture<O> result = Futures.transform(future, new AsyncFunction<List<T>, O>() {
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<O> apply(final List<T> input) {
        // Begin other tasks using `input` (the set of results from the first tasks)
    }
});
```

This would be beneficial if you want to wait on the resulting [ListenableFuture](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html), or potentially add a third set of tasks that need to happen upon completion of the second set.

Comment: The point was that none of the tasks should start until I have collected all of the `Future`s. How does this help?

Comment: I should've been a bit more clear in my answer - I can update when I get home. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but it sounds like you have a set of Futures and a set of tasks that need the result of all of those Futures before they can execute - is that correct? If so, then you can combine those Futures into a single one. Then, you can queue an asynchronous task which will only execute once the given Future is complete. In this case, that given future would actually contain the results of all of those first tasks.

Comment: It's not another set of tasks that needs the *result* of a prior set of tasks. I want a single set of tasks to have access to each other's *Futures* before they begin executing.

Comment: Ah I see now - my mistake. Out of curiosity, did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: Not using executors. I just created a bunch of threads and then started them.